# how to add object to a list only if list is not null and isn't already in a list?

Tags: java, list

For example

```
private ArrayList<Circles> circles;
```

Now I need a method like this

```
public boolean addCircle(Circle circle) {
}
```

How would I go about doing so while satisfying the requirements in the title?

Comment: You should use a Set as it doesn't allow duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

You could make use of the `contains()` method on `ArrayList`. However, this will get slower and slower as the list gets larger.

Unless you really need `List` semantics you should consider using a `Set` as these prevent duplicates. If you wish to maintain insertion order when iterating (like a `List`) then you can use a `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: You could also use both structures: a `List` for ordering, and a `Set` for duplicate-detection. `if (set.add(e)) { list.add(e); }`. That way you can also sort the list, etc. If you go that route, it'd be best to wrap both of those objects in a simple class that provides `add`, `get(int index)`, etc.

Comment: Definitely a good way to do it a `UniqueEntryList` or some such. However, I don't think you can produce a class that fully obeys the `List` interface and includes duplicate detection. For example the `add( index, element)` method doesn't return a `boolean` to indicate failure, unlike `add(element)`.

Comment: Yes, I was unclear. I wasn't suggesting that the wrapper class implement `List` (or `Set` for that matter). Just provide the few methods you need. If you need it as a list, I would recommend a method `List<T> asList()` that returns the internal `List` structure, _wrapped in `Collections.unmodifiableList`_. That way the user can't accidentally (or maliciously) add elements and thus break the relationship with the set.

Comment: Something like this, to make it more concrete: https://gist.github.com/yshavit/9587889

Comment: ensure that the class contained in the collection has appropriate hashCode and equals methods

Answer (score 0):

see the [ArrayList.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method for how to check if the item is in the list.
you can add items to the list with the [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) method.

Comment: Altough is correct, `addCircle()` operation will take `O(n)` plus,`add` in arrayList is already O(n) i guess. Using another data-structure if op can change like a `Set` will be more efficient.

Comment: That depends on how may items will be in the list I suppose, or depend on other requirements from the data structure. The question was on an ArrayList - and so was my answer :)

Comment: @nachokk `ArrayList.add` is O(1) amortized. Some adds may take longer (if they need to resize), but most are constant time. In other words, adding `n` elements will take `O(n)` tim.

Comment: @yshavit then that is not Big-O notation i think, i though that Big-O is just for the worst case, for average case it uses another letter :P

Comment: @nachokk That's true, but it's a bit misleading to say that `ArrayList.add` is `O(n)`; it's true, but draws the opposite of the conclusion you should draw except in certain, specific cases (like real-time systems). And if you want to get _really_ technical, since `ArrayList` is backed by an array, and arrays can't be bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, `ArrayList.add` is actually O(1) where the constant is very big; if `N` grows larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, it'll just throw an exception. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private ArrayList<Circle> circles;

public boolean addCircle(Circle circle) {
    if(circle != null && circles != null && !circles.contains(circle)){
        circles.add(circle);
    }

}
```

However please remember that your have to override the equals method in your circle class. Because the contains method internally calls .equals & .hashcode methods.

Comment: `equals` therefore  `hashCode` too and properly to follow the contract, contains doesn't call hashCode().

Comment: Its a best practice to override both methods. However in the arraylist implementation, The contains method calls indexOf method and only .equals method is used within the indexOf method for the comparison. However I have updated the post as per your comment. Thanks.